# What does 'load' do in Lua?

Tags: lua, load

I was Trying to sove my problem in understanding `load` function in Lua Scripts but there was not any Examples or guides for this command . it tells in his own Lua Website https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load this :

`load (ld [, source [, mode [, env]]])`

can someone describe it to me please ?

Comment: `load` converts Lua source code to Lua function.

Comment: Is [Language constructs will be explained using the usual extended BNF notation, in which {a} means 0 or more a's, and \[a\] means an optional a](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3) the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`load` takes a chunk, compiles it, and returns as a function that can be called to execute the chunk. For example, the following will create a function that will `add` two numbers together:

```
local func, err = load("return function(a,b) return a+b end")
if func then
  local ok, add = pcall(func)
  if ok then
    print(add(2,3))
  else
    print("Execution error:", add)
  end
else
  print("Compilation error:", err)
end
```

This should print `5`.

Comment: Did you mean using `pcall` to get func() execution error?

Comment: Indeed; fixed. Thanks!