# When using load() to use a string as a function. It returns "attempt to call a nil value"

Tags: lua, love2d

So I'm working on a game and I want to use a string that can be called as a function so I can quickly call multiple functions all at once. I have an example of something I'm trying to get work:

```
function state_machine_1()
    print("Hello world")
end

function state_machine_2()
    print("Goodbye world")
end

local func="state_machine_".."1"
load(func)()

func="state_machine_".."2"
load(func)()
```

When I run the code in the lua demo site I get the exact same error now which is "attempt to call a nil value". I've tried looking it up but load() is too vague for search engines to know even with context. Any ideas of what I can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nil error happens because it fails to compile the code

You can add an assert to catch the compile error

```
assert(load(func))()
```

The reason it fails because `func` should end with `()` for it to be a function call.

```
local func = "state_machine_" .. "1" .. "()"

assert(load(func))()
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to define the functions in a table and use the table top lookup the function you want like this:

```
local funcs = {}

function funcs.state_machine_1()
  print("Hello World")
end

funcs.state_machine_2 = function() -- another to define the function in a table
  print("Goodbye World")
end

local func = "state_machine_" .. "1"

funcs[ func ]()

func = "state_machine_" .. "2"

funcs[ func ]()
```

The load function takes a string containing actual Lua code:
[what do 'load' do in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629129/what-do-load-do-in-lua)

Comment: That's not bad at all. Not exactly what I was looking for but if it's the only answer I can get then I'll take it.

Comment: Thank you so much. The missing .."()" is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Just a string. - There is another kind of string in Lua5.3 that is extremly usefull for different kinds of code. I use it for an HTML module that holds different code like: HTML, CSS, JavaScript, SVG with as much lines as needed. Try it in Lua: ```foo=[[return '<div style="color:red;">bar</div>']]``` Executing: ```print(load(foo)())```